# How to mix point-estimate with Bayesian estimate in pymc3?

Tags: pymc3

Suppose I have a simple model, y=a*x+b
I want to model a =pymc3.Normal('a',mu=0,sd=1.,shape=(1)), a normal distribution, and I want to make b as an unknown constant.
Then how to assign a pymc3 object to b?
Thank you.

Comment: If you don't know the value of `b` then it should be a probability distribution. Everything you do not know in a Bayesian analysis is represented by a probability distribution.

Comment: Do you want to get a point-estimate of `b`? In that case, you can compute the posterior and then just report the mean (or another summary statistic) of `b`.